# PHP DOMDocument: what is the nicest way to safely add text to an element

Tags: php, xml, special-characters, domdocument

When adding a string that might contain troublesome characters (eg &, <, >), DOMDocument throws a warning, rather than sanitizing the string.

**I'm looking for a succinct way to make strings xml-safe - ideally something that leverages the DOMDocument library.**

I'm looking for something better than `preg_replace` or `htmlspecialchars`.  I see `DOMDocument::createTextNode()`, but the resulting DOMText object is cumbersome and can't be handed to `DOMDocument::createElement()`.

To illustrate the problem, this code:

```
<?php 

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$parent = $dom->createElement('rootNode');
$parent->appendChild( $dom->createElement('name', 'this ampersand causes pain & sorrow ') );
$dom->appendChild( $parent );
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

produces this result (see [eval.in](https://eval.in/278737)):

```
Warning: DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference          sorrow in /tmp/execpad-41ee778d3376/source-41ee778d3376 on line 6
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootNode>
  <name>this ampersand causes pain </name>
</rootNode>
```

Comment: "Better than preg_replace or htmlspecialchars" - better in what respect?

Comment: preg_replace and htmlspecialchars are broad-spectrum tools.  A preg_replace approach depends fully on the developer's knowledge of xml character issues.  The  htmlspecialcharacters approach [seems to be disputed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822774/php-is-htmlentities-sufficient-for-creating-xml-safe-values).  And since this issue is endemic to XML, I would expect an XML library to provide clean ways to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create the text node and append it. I described the problem in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22957785/2265374

However you can extend `DOMDocument` and overload `createElement*()`.

```
class MyDOMDocument extends DOMDocument {

  public function createElement($name, $content = '') {
    $node = parent::createElement($name);
    if ((string)$content !== '') {
      $node->appendChild($this->createTextNode($content));
    }
    return $node;
  }

  public function createElementNS($namespace, $name, $content = '') {
    $node = parent::createElementNS($namespace, $name);
    if ((string)$content !== '') {
      $node->appendChild($this->createTextNode($content));
    }
    return $node;
  }
}

$dom = new MyDOMDocument();
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('foo'));
$root->appendChild($dom->createElement('bar', 'Company & Son'));
$root->appendChild($dom->createElementNS('urn:bar', 'bar', 'Company & Son'));

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
  <bar>Company &amp; Son</bar>
  <bar xmlns="urn:bar">Company &amp; Son</bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: And unfortunately to be fair, the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) does say this as well: _The value will not be escaped. Use DOMDocument::createTextNode() to create a text node with escaping support._

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure I use to build XML elements, the second part is usually wrapped in a function.

```
$parent = $document->documentElement; // pick the node we want to append to
$name = 'foo'; // new element name
$content = 'bar < not a tag > <![CDATA[" testing cdata "]]>'; // content

$element = ($parent->ownerDocument) ? $parent->ownerDocument->createElement($name) : $parent->createElement($name);
$parent->appendchild($element);
$element->appendchild($parent->ownerDocument->createTextNode($content));
```

my function will then `return $element`