# How to handle special HTML characters in DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Let's say I build an HTML fragment using the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$header = $dom->createElement("h2", "Lorem & Ipsum");
$dom->appendChild($header);
print($dom->saveHTML());
```

The raw HTML code printed contains the unescaped `&` symbol instead of the necessary HTML `&amp;`. The code also throws the following PHP error:

> Warning:  DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference

What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350112/php-domdocument-what-is-the-nicest-way-to-safely-add-text-to-an-element & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956330/cakephp-xml-utility-library-triggers-domdocument-warning/22957785#22957785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the PHP team is not willing to change this behavior ([source](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31191)), so we have to find a workaround instead.

One way is to simply do the encoding yourself in the PHP code, as such:

```
$header = $dom->createElement("h2", "Lorem &amp; Ipsum");
```

However, this isn't always convenient, as the text printed may be inside of a variable or contain other special characters besides `&`. So, you can use the [`htmlentities`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

```
$text = "Lorem & Ipsum";
$header = $dom->createElement("h2", htmlentities($text));
```

If this still is not an ideal solution, another workaround is to use the `textContent` property instead of the second argument in `createElement`.

In the code below, I've implemented this in a `DOMDocument` subclass, so you just have to use the `BetterDOM` subclass instead to fix this strange bug.

```
class BetterDOM extends DOMDocument {
    public function createElement($tag, $text = null) {
        $base = parent::createElement($tag);
        $base->textContent = $text;
        return $base;
    }
}

// Correctly prints "<h2>Lorem &amp; Ipsum</h2>" with no errors
$dom = new BetterDOM();
$header = $dom->createElement("h2", "Lorem & Ipsum");
$dom->appendChild($header);
print($dom->saveHTML());
```